# Не работает парсинг bs4 на сервере heroku

Tags: python, beautiful-soup, heroku

Локально парсер работает правильно, но на heroku он возвращает пустой список.

Парсер:

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def parser_links():
    URL = 'https://site.com/'
    HEADERS = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36',
    }

    response = requests.get(URL, headers=HEADERS)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.findAll('div', class_='download')
    comps = []

    for item in items:
        if item.find('a', href=True)['href'][0] == '/':
            comps.append(
                item.find('a', href=True)['href']
            )
    return comps
```

Comment: Проверьте что в `response.content` приходит. Мб тот сайт препятствует работе с heroku, смотря на ip

Comment: @gil9red Вы правы, возвращает `Response 403`.