# Когда я подключаю бота к heroku у меня не парсятся данные с avito

Tags: python, telebot, heroku, parse

У меня есть бот который парсит данные с авито, когда я размещаю его на heroku мне выдают ошибку:

```
app[bot.1]: File "/app/parse/Parse.py", line 14, in get_content
app[bot.1]: for div_it in div.find_all('div', {'data-marker': 'item'}):
app[bot.1]: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

но на локальном сервере данные парсятся

```
def __init__(self, url):
    self.url = url
    self.values = []
    source = requests.get(self.url)
    self.html = BS(source.text, 'lxml')

def get_content(self):
    div = self.html.find('div', {'data-marker': 'catalog-serp'})      
    for div_it in div.find_all('div', {'data-marker': 'item'}):
        div_it_cont = div_it.find('div', {'class': 'iva-item-content-m2FiN'})
```

Подскажите в чем проблема, буду благодарен

Comment: посмотрите что возвращает `source`, возможно `ip` `heroku` забанены.

Comment: Sherlock, извините за глупый вопрос, но где это посмотреть? И heroku local парсит данные, это не значит что ip не забанен?

Comment: Сделайте `print(source)` после строки `source = requests.get(self.url)` и посмотрите, что он возвращает?

Comment: согласен с @Sherlock: возможно, что ip heroku забанен на стороне avito... 
[возможный дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1229680/420098), хотя ответ там только в коментарии

Comment: @Sherlock, Как вы справились с этой проблемой?