# Ошибка IndexError: list index out of range в PythonAnywhere

Tags: python, бот, развертывание

Данная ошибка появляется только на сайте PythonAnywhere при нажатии на кнопку "Узнать числитель или знаменатель". Не знаю как её решить.

Имею следующий код

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

bot = telebot.TeleBot('')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['stop'])
def stop(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Бот остановлен', reply_markup=markup2)
markup2 = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True)
begin = types.KeyboardButton('/start')
markup2.add(begin)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Что ты хочешь от меня ?', reply_markup=markup1)
markup1 = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True)
itembtna = types.KeyboardButton('Сайт')
itembtnv = types.KeyboardButton('Расписание')
itembtnc = types.KeyboardButton('❓Информация по всем Учителям❓')
itembtnd = types.KeyboardButton('Архив учебников')
itembtnh = types.KeyboardButton('Домашние задание на семестр')
itembtnk = types.KeyboardButton('Узнать числитель или знаменатель')
markup1.row(itembtna, itembtnv, itembtnc)
markup1.row(itembtnd, itembtnh, itembtnk)

markup2 = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True)
begin = types.KeyboardButton('/start')
markup2.add(begin)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def bot_message(message):

    if message.text == 'Узнать числитель или знаменатель':
        Znach = 'Сайт'
        headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}
        full_page = requests.get(Znach, headers=headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(full_page.content, 'html.parser')
        convert = soup.findAll("font")
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'На этой недели: ' + convert[0].text)
```

Comment: Добавьте код ошибки. Проблема скорее всего в парсинге, хост заблокирован на стороне сайта. Такая [ошибка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1229680/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3-bs4-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5-heroku) часто встречается на бесплатных серверах **heroku** и **pythonwhere**

Comment: А тут он не пишет код ошибки. Он просто выдаёт IndexError: list index out of range и после он останавливает бота.

Comment: У вас индексация в коде только в одном месте `convert[0].text`, значит список `convert` пустой получается. Вы можете этот факт проверять и выдавать какое-то другое сообщение в этом случае. Но скорее всего это будет выдаваться всегда. Переходите на другой хостинг, что тут ещё сказать.